# MySQL: Look for the same string in multiple columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql, search

I am trying to make a search-page-like function.  I want to make a query to look for "query" in "ColumnA" and "ColumnB" and "ColumnC" and "ColumnD". And select the rows which has the word/phrase "query" in any of those columns.
This appears to work:

```
   SELECT * FROM projects
   WHERE 
   category LIKE '%query%' OR
   name LIKE '%query%' OR 
   description LIKE '%query%'OR 
   keywords LIKE '%query%' OR 
   'type' LIKE '%query%'  
   ORDER BY name ASC
```

But it is lengthy. Is there any easier or more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: best option is to create an many to many relationship with search words llnkt to your projects table this way you can avoid using like '%%' (would require an full index scan or full table scan) or the use off an FULL TEXT index..

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Simple workaround:

```
SELECT * 
FROM projects 
WHERE 
    CONCAT(category,name,description,keywords,type) LIKE '%query%' 
ORDER BY name ASC;
```

You can add separators between columns if needed:

```
SELECT * 
FROM projects 
WHERE 
    CONCAT(category,"|",name,"|",description,"|",keywords,"|",type) LIKE '%query%' 
ORDER BY name ASC;
```

You can also use a fulltext search (you need to create a fulltext index as described here: [How do FULLTEXT INDEXES on multiple columns work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12361804/how-do-fulltext-indexes-on-multiple-columns-work))

```
SELECT *, MATCH (category,name,description,keywords,type) AGAINST ('query') AS score FROM projects WHERE MATCH (category,name,description,keywords,type) AGAINST ('query');
```

Comment: You can use `CONCAT_WS('|', category, name, ...)` for your second query. I would even use it for the first query with an empty separator, because CONCAT_WS() will ignore NULL columns, while CONCAT() will return NULL if only one column is NULL.

Answer (score 1):

**But it is lengthy.**

I think this is not problem. query can be generated client side.

**Is there any easier or more efficient way of doing this?**

use Sphinx or Solr with MySQL. It is not difficult and super fast. Here is Sphinx example. http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-php-sphinxsearch/

and I think `CONCAT` is not efficient than yours, there is cost to concatenate columns (some columns can be long text). `CONCAT(name, description) LIKE '%query%'` reads `name` and `description` and concat two values after that LIKE is applied. that means all columns READ twice, while your query can be completed just first column is matched. All condition is "OR", so `category` column matches %query% that row does not need to be compared to 'name' column.

**FYI**

just FYI, below query can check, which column has more 'query'

```
SELECT name,
  (LENGTH(category) - LENGTH(REPLACE(category, 'query', ''))) / LENGTH('query') as category_match_cnt,
  (LENGTH(name) - LENGTH(REPLACE(name, 'query', ''))) / LENGTH('query') as name_match_cnt,
  (LENGTH(description) - LENGTH(REPLACE(description, 'query', ''))) / LENGTH('query') as desc_match_cnt,
```