# MYSQL match against query in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want to use the MATCH AGAINST query instead of like. I want to search in my database for a certain value whose attribute is not specified (like WHERE id = 2045).
I have a search bar like google in my site and I want to write for example: 2045 or John and this gives me all about it. I dont want to search only for years ou names. I already have this for a specific attribute as name:

```
$name = $_POST["name"];

$sql="SELECT id, name, city FROM student WHERE name LIKE '".$name."%'";
```

But what I want is something with the MATCH AGAINST query. I don't know how to do that... This is what I have:

```
$sql ="SELECT id, name, city FROM student WHERE MATCH(id, name, city) AGAINST ('".$name."%')";
```

Here, I want my $name to be something random that I wrote in my search bar.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Do you've any specific reason not using multipe `LIKE` with `OR`?

```
$name = $_POST["name"];
$sql="SELECT id, name, city FROM student 
     WHERE id LIKE '".$name."%'" OR
           name LIKE '".$name."%'" OR
           city LIKE '".$name."%'";
```

Another way to do it using `CONCAT()`,

```
$sql="SELECT id, name, city FROM student WHERE CONCAT(id,name,city) LIKE '".$name."%'";
```

Comment: thank you so much!!! it really worked but if I have 100 attributes, it will be really hard working. Do you know how to do that for 100 attributes? Also, the `CONCAT()` didn't work, only for ID.

Comment: Then try fulltext search with match ...against. See here more https://stackoverflow.com/a/20301388/1138192