# Perform a where() on ALL columns in a model (Laravel)

Tags: laravel

I'd like to do a `where()` on ALL columns within my model, for example in ANY column I'd like to find the string "123", not just for a single column ALL columns (without chaining a `whereOr()`

For example, the database has

`| Title | Body1 | Body2| Body3|
My Model    foo      foo    123`

and then do a where() on all columns.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you provide an example query and the desired result? Are you willing to use an AND, OR, or maybe perform a sort of fuzzy search over your model attributes?

Comment: @alariva I'd like to get `My Model` and yes

Comment: Looks like you are willing to do something like this https://murze.be/searching-models-using-a-where-like-query-in-laravel

Comment: @alariva that only searches through one of the elements, I want to search through all of them

Comment: You could construct a raw SQL query to do a FULL TEXT search over multiple columns. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12361804/how-do-fulltext-indexes-on-multiple-columns-work

Comment: Do you mean the attributes (by elements)? If you take a careful look you will see the technique allows you to pass-in an array of the attributes you want to search for.

Comment: @alariva Sorry about that, I had an issue with my serverside code, thank you very much for your help

Comment: Cool. Thanks. Also checkout Nathan suggestion on fulltext search which might be an absolutely different alternative for your convenience.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you aren't going to chain where(), this is the best way to do this.

```
    $columns = ['Title','Body1','Body2','Body3'];
    $query = ModelName::select('*');
    foreach($columns as $column)
    {
     $query->orWhere($column, '=', '123');
   }
   $models = $query->get();
```

This may save like a small but considerable chunk of time as compared to chaining a bunch of where() statements in your code. 
Hope this helped !!!