# Search across multiple columns and get the best match

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database table similar to this:

```
+------------------+-----------------+------------+-----------------+
|   businessname   |     street      |    city    |     country     |
+------------------+-----------------+------------+-----------------+
| McDonalds        | idkstreet 11    | Amsterdam  | the Netherlands |
| Bloomberg        | somethingave 33 | New York   | USA             |
| Stackoverflow HQ | idkbro 23       | California | USA             |
+------------------+-----------------+------------+-----------------+
```

I'm trying to achieve a way of searching across multiple columns with a combined string as a query, for example when I type:

**Bloomberg New York** 
It should result to the **second** row in the table.

or when I type:
**McDonalds netherlands amsterdam**
It should result to the **first** row in the table.

However one column only stores the business name and the other columns store the street, city, country, etc.
So what would be the best way/query to search a combined string over multiple columns and get the best result?

I can't find an answer anywhere so I'm not able to make a code example.

I hope my explanation is clear enough, 
thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you requiring a full match?  I suspect that you want full text search, given your examples.

Comment: @GordonLinoff No, but it would be nice to filter the results based on the best match (if that is even possible)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use fulltext index for the column you want to query. Then when retrieving data, you can use “union” to combine returned data.

Reference: how to add fulltext index and write a quẻry to fill text search http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-natural-language-search.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a fulltext index on multiple columns. This is described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26803775/378779.

`` ALTER TABLE `your_table` ADD FULLTEXT `your_index_name` (`businessname`, `street`, `city`, `country`); ``

To search:

`` SELECT *, MATCH( `businessname`, `street`, `city`, `country` ) against ("Bloomberg New York" ) FROM `your_table` ``